# SSRS - Expression returning error if null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm expecting only the names to appear on the calendar if they exist and nothing if they don't.

I created an expression where it returns only the last name of a person by using the comma as a delimiter.

**My current expression:**

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!EmployeeName.Value), nothing, Left(Fields!EmployeeName.Value,-1 + InStr(Fields!EmployeeName.Value, ",")))
```

**Current results where #Error appears if a name doesn't exist:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occuring because you are passing in a number less than 0 to the left function. When your string does not have a comma in it you are passing in -1.

To handle this I added two if statements to the expression. The first will return the whole string if the index of the first comma is 0. The second checks for the -1 condition and passes a 0 to the left function when that occurs.

```
=
iif(
    IsNothing(Fields!EmployeeName.Value), 
    nothing, 
    iif(
        InStr(Fields!EmployeeName.Value, ",") = 0, 
        Fields!EmployeeName.Value, 
        Left(Fields!EmployeeName.Value,iif(-1 + InStr(Fields!EmployeeName.Value, ",") < 0, 0, -1 + InStr(Fields!EmployeeName.Value, ",")))
        )
    )
```